# DB Deployment with MsBuild

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration

Anyone got examples of how to do a DB deployment without TFS in MSBuild.  I had automated db deployments in nant at an old position, but need to do it in msbuild at a new job.  I was using the nant and setting a boolean flag to trigger processing sql files, but im unsure of how to do this in msbuild.  Everything surprising with MSBuild points to TFS

I was using the following algorithm

```
//  Set run updates = false
//  Store DB Version from Version Table
//  For each file in SQL directory
//    if file == db version
//      set run updates = true
//    else if run updates
//      run sql in file
//      update db version
```

I'm open to changes in how this is handled... but can't forsee my company moving to TFS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to use [DBDeploy](http://dbdeploy.com/) to do the database deployments.  The following works in my situation.

```
  <Target Name="DeployDB">
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\temp" ContinueOnError="true" />
    <MakeDir Directories="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\temp" ContinueOnError="true" />
    <Exec Command="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\lib\dbdeploy\example\tools\nant\bin\nant -buildfile:dbdeploy.build -D:DBConnstring=&quot;$(MainDatabaseConnectionString)&quot; -D:SQLDirectory=..\DB -D:OutputFile=..\Temp\Deploy.sql" />
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.SqlServer.SqlExecute TaskAction="Execute" Files="..\Temp\Deploy.sql" ConnectionString="$(MainDatabaseConnectionString)" />
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\temp" ContinueOnError="true" />
  </Target>
```

with a build file of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="dbdeploy_example" default="generate-script" basedir="." xmlns="http://nant.sf.net/release/0.85/nant.xsd">
  <loadtasks assembly="../lib/DbDeploy/bin/Net.Sf.Dbdeploy.dll" />
  <property name="DBConnstring" value="Server=localhost;Initial Catalog=XXXX;Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
  <property name="SQLDirectory" value="." />
  <property name="OutputFile" value="deploy.sql" />
  <property name="UndoOutput" value="deploy-undo.sql" />

  <target name="generate-script" description="generate a sql upgrade script">
    <echo message="DBConstring: ${DBConnstring}" />
    <echo message="SQLDirectory: ${SQLDirectory}" />
    <echo message="OutputFile: ${OutputFile}" />
    <echo message="UndoOutput: ${UndoOutput}" />
    <dbdeploy dbType="mssql"
      dbConnection="${DBConnstring}"
      dir="${SQLDirectory}"
      outputFile="${OutputFile}"
      undoOutputFile="${UndoOutput}" />
  </target>
</project>
```